# Get the node where you write

Tags: javascript

I want to get the node where the cursor is when it is being written

```js
document.getElementById('parent').addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {

  console.log(e.target);
});
```

```css
.root {
  padding-right: 1px;
}

#parent>div {
  border-color: yellow;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" contenteditable=true style="border: black 2px solid; height:200px">
  <div class="root" id="1">Qué</div>
  <div class="root" id="2">es</div>
  <div class="root" id="3">Lorem</div>
  <div class="root" id="4">Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

the problem is complicated because I am using for each word a div.

I need to use div so you can display the suggestions in the words (I'm doing a spellchecker)

[image]

Comment: So you need to do a list of suggestions based on the word the user has typed. To do that better use keyup event to get the word after being typed and not before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`window.getSelection()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) to get the actual node under the cursor:

```js
document.getElementById('parent').addEventListener('keydown', event => {
  const actualTarget = window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode;
  console.log(actualTarget);
});
```

```css
.root {
  padding-right: 1px;
}

#parent>div {
  border-color: yellow;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" contenteditable="true" style="border: black 2px solid; height:200px">
  <div class="root" id="1">Qué</div>
  <div class="root" id="2">es</div>
  <div class="root" id="3">Lorem</div>
  <div class="root" id="4">Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach. I suggest you to use **keyup** event to get the final word after typed to generate your list of suggestions:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.root').forEach(function(el) {
// Do stuff here
 el.onkeyup = function(e){
     console.log(e.target);
  };

});
```

```css
.root {
  padding-right: 1px;
}

#parent>div {
  border-color: yellow;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" style="border: black 2px solid; height:200px">
  <div class="root" contenteditable="true" id="1">Qué</div>
  <div class="root" contenteditable="true" id="2">es</div>
  <div class="root" contenteditable="true" id="3">Lorem</div>
  <div class="root" contenteditable="true" id="4">Ipsum</div>
</div>
```